# Make Spacemacs server/daemon not share windows in different frames

Tags: windows, emacs, daemon, frames, spacemacs

When I create new frames, they all share the windows.
If I have 2 frames and 2 windows (with different buffers), the other frame will list the window number as 2 instead of 1.

I want to have the frames have their own window list starting at 1 so that I can M-<n> in that frame and not worry about other frames.

Does anybody know a variable I can customize for this, or any way to achieve what I want?

Edit: This is a spacemacs specific thing relating to the server.
The command that is used is:

`winum-select-window-1 ; M-1`

And M-n is for the nth window.

I looked at winnum.el and it seems to support frames having their own window lists, which is the behavior with non daemon mode.

A relevant variable might be `winum--numbers-table` which stores a hash-table of numbers to windows.
Perhaps some code can be written to modify this table so that a new frame creation keeps its own hash-table.
I have no idea on how to this right now however.

Comment: @phils Ok, here's what I mean, take a look: http://0x0.st/-hHx.png . Notice the frame on the right has the window number at the left bottom corner being 2, but I'd like it to be 1 instead. This is in daemon mode btw. I'm aware that launching in non daemon mode my issue is solved, but I don't want to use non daemon mode, because then I couldn't share the buffers across the frames, plus startup time.

Comment: @phils So you're saying that standard emacs daemon doesn't have this issue and that it's probably a spacemacs issue?

Comment: @phils Yeah you're right, it doesn't have numbered windows. Thanks for bringing this up. Still, there must be a way to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with client/server as far as I can see, and the behaviour you want is already supported by winum.el: you can simply customize the `winum-scope` user option to be `frame-local`; or use:

```el
(setq winum-scope 'frame-local)
```

I don't think Spacemacs will be a factor unless it's also setting the scope explicitly, in which case you may need to ensure that your config takes precedence.  (I just tested by installing winum.el; I'm not using Spacemacs.)